# Freeipa SSH Pubkey + OTP without Password

Tags: ssh, pam, one-time-password, freeipa, sssd

Does anyone know how to configure a host connected to Freeipa so that 2FA passes by SSH PubKey + OTP, and not by password + OTP?

my sshd_config include:

```
UsePAM yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive:pam
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is possible, because the pubkey authentication happens from inside sshd even before sshd runs the PAM authentication. But try asking on freeipa-users, the helpful folks there might have an answer.